# 'std::is_convertible<ArgTypes,ValidTraits>::value': dependent name is not a type; And error C2059: syntax error: '...'

Tags: c++, templates, chromium

1、When I compile chromium code

```
    template <class ValidTraits, class... ArgTypes>
    struct AreValidTraits
        : std::integral_constant<
        bool,
        all_of({std::is_convertible<ArgTypes, ValidTraits>::value...}) > {};
```

there are some error:

```
    base\task\task_traits_details.h(169): warning C4346: 'std::is_convertible<ArgTypes,ValidTraits>::value': dependent name is not a type
base\task\task_traits_details.h(169): note: prefix with 'typename' to indicate a type
base\task\task_traits_details.h(171): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'base::trait_helpers::AreValidTraits<ValidTraits,ArgTypes...>' being compiled
base\task\task_traits_details.h(171): error C2059: syntax error: '...'
base\task\task_traits_details.h(169): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '}'
base\task\task_traits_details.h(169): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before ';'
base\task\task_traits_details.h(169): error C2143: syntax error: missing '>' before ';'
base\task\task_traits_details.h(169): error C3770: 'unknown-type': is not a valid base class
base\task\task_traits_details.h(169): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ';'
base\task\task_traits_details.h(169): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
```

2、So I add ‘typename’ before 'std::is_convertible', but the problem is still not resolved, here is the modified code:

```
        template <class ValidTraits, class... ArgTypes>
    struct AreValidTraits
        : std::integral_constant<
        bool,
        all_of({typename std::is_convertible<ArgTypes, ValidTraits>::value...}) > {};
```

and the same error:

```
base\task\task_traits_details.h(171): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
base\task\task_traits_details.h(171): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'base::trait_helpers::AreValidTraits<ValidTraits,ArgTypes...>' being compiled
base\task\task_traits_details.h(171): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '}'
base\task\task_traits_details.h(171): error C2143: syntax error: missing '>' before ';'
base\task\task_traits_details.h(171): error C3770: 'unknown-type': is not a valid base class
base\task\task_traits_details.h(171): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ';'
base\task\task_traits_details.h(171): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
```

it seems the modify just solve the first warning.
but the chromium code is no problem, i am using vs2017 compiler.
don't know what's wrong with these errors?

here is all_of function code：

```
    // Checks if all of the elements in |ilist| are true.
    // Similar to std::any_of for the case of constexpr initializer_list.
    inline constexpr bool all_of(std::initializer_list<bool> ilist) {
        for (auto c : ilist) {
            if (!c)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: What's `all_of`?

Comment: How are you building chromium? If it doesn't build following the instructions provided in chromium's documentation properly, then file a bug report with the project. Don't try to modify the source code without knowing what it does.

Comment: I've already added the all_of function code in the end

Comment: compile chromium using ninja is ok, but i want use the base project in my vs program solution, so i create a project using chromium base code, i really don't want to modify the source code, it's too complicated, but now the error block my work, i need to fix it. so i want to know the reason of the compile error?

Comment: I think chromium is build with clang on Windows. I wouldn't be sure that msvc is supported at all. This particular error seems like a bug in msvc to me, it doesn't seem to like the pack expansion inside the braced-init-list at all.